# Simile Timeline displays when opened directly but not when opened by servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, timeline, simile

Essentially I have a servlet that opens a page timeline.html which uses the simile timeline widget.
When the webpage is opened directly from user.dir/timeline.html, the timeline displays perfectly.
But when the webpage is opened by the servlet on localhost:8080, it does not load the xml file.

Do you have any idea why?

```
if (action.equals("create")) {
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/timeline.html").forward(request, response); }
```

Timeline code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Timeline</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
 <script src="http://api.simile-widgets.org/timeline/2.3.1/timeline-api.js?bundle=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
   function onLoad() {
   var eventSource = new Timeline.DefaultEventSource();
  var bandInfos = [
 Timeline.createBandInfo({
     eventSource:    eventSource,
     date:           "Jun 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT",
     width:          "70%", 
     intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MONTH, 
     intervalPixels: 100
 }),
 Timeline.createBandInfo({
     overview:       true,
     eventSource:    eventSource,
     date:           "Jun 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT",
     width:          "30%", 
     intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.YEAR, 
     intervalPixels: 200
 })
 ];
 bandInfos[1].syncWith = 0;
 bandInfos[1].highlight = true;

 tl = Timeline.create(document.getElementById("my-timeline"), bandInfos);
 Timeline.loadXML("/timeline.xml", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url); });}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();" onresize="onResize();">
   <div id="my-timeline" style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid #aaa"></div>
   <noscript>
This page uses Javascript to show you a Timeline. Please enable Javascript in your browser to see the full page. Thank you.
</noscript>
```

Comment: what error do you get? Which url works? Which doesnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/timeline.xml` refers to your webapplication context root location. are you placing the xml file in the root location. For example , if you have your webapp called `myapp` deployed in `webapps/myapp`  , then `'/'` refers to myapp directory. So `/timeline.xml` refers to `myapp/timeline.xml`